# Can I set AlertManager repeat_interval for a specific receiver/alert?

Tags: alert, prometheus

We are using Prometheus to send alerts. We have a global `repeat_interval` route of 10 hours as default, but I would like to up this to 200 hours for a specific receiver/type of alert.

I have already upped the `--data.retention` to 200 hours (as it defaults to 120h), but I don't want to change the default `repeat_interval`, only for a specified receiver.

This is my `alertmanager.yml`:

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m

route:
  repeat_interval: 10h

  routes:
    - match:
        severity: 'critical' 
        receiver: 'email' 
        continue: true

receivers:
  - name: 'email'
    email_configs:
      - to: "my@email.com" 
        from: "{{from}}" 
        ...
        headers: 
          subject: "SUBJECT"

  - (other receivers...)
```

I would want to set the `repeat_interval` of `email`-receivers to 200h, but keep the default `route`-`repeat_interval` to 10h. **Is this possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
route:
  repeat_interval: 10h

  routes:
    - match:
        severity: 'critical' 
      receiver: 'email' 
      repeat_interval: 200h
      continue: true
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I have multiple sorts of emails but I only want the repeat_interval to be set to 200h for a specific job?

Could I add a "job: <my_job>" within the match? to make it specific to that kind of job

Comment: Yes, you can use any label you have to that specific metric/alert (ex: job, instance, alertname, mountpoint, etc)